# ImportError: No module named sysconfig--can't get pip working

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, yum

I'm really struggling with pip on a RedHat 6.9 system. Every time I tried to use pip, I got

```
ImportError: No module named sysconfig
```

I tried Googling for solutions. I don't have apt-get and can't seem to get it with yum, so purging setuptools was out of the question. I did my best to delete setuptools by hand so I could reinstall them, but yum is convinced there are still setuptools on the machine.

Pretty much any of the advice involving downloading something with yum doesn't work for me. Yum always says it can't find what I'm looking for. So if there's a way I can download something without yum or apt-get (for example, not through the terminal), that would probably be best.

I have both Python 3 and Python 2 on my machine, so I don't know if that will change the advice that you guys can give me.

1000 thanks to anyone who can help! Right now I can only get things done through anaconda interfaces (such as Jupyter notebooks and Spyder) which is really limiting.

**EDIT:** Here is my error trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/bin/pip2", line 5, in <module>

    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 947, in <module>

    class Environment(object):

  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 951, in Environment

    self, search_path=None, platform=get_supported_platform(),

  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 180, in get_supported_platform

    plat = get_build_platform()

  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 380, in get_build_platform

    from sysconfig import get_platform

ImportError: No module named sysconfig
```

**EDIT 2:** @hoefling requested that I post the output of the following commands; first:

```
$ yum list installed | grep setuptools
*Note* Red Hat Network repositories are not listed below. You must run this command as root to access RHN repositories.
python-setuptools.noarch     0.6.10-4.el6_9      @ncep-base-x86_64-workstation-6
```

and:

```
$ grep ^Version: /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-*.egg-info/PKG-INFO
grep: /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-*.egg-info/PKG-INFO: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Which version of Python 2?  Sounds like you have a broken python installation.

Comment: @chrisz it's Python 2.6.6 and Python 3.4.3. I am trying to use pip with Python 3 if that makes a difference.  I agree that it probably is broken.

Comment: Most probably `pip` points to `python2.6`, if you enter `pip -V`, where does the location path point to? If this is true - what is your `setuptools` version for `python2.6`? Run `python2.6 -c "import setuptools; print(setuptools.__version__)"` to check that. Most probably you have updated `setuptools` beyond version 37 that dropped support for Python 2.6.

Comment: @hoefling I cannot run pip -V. I still get the same ImportError. As for the second recommendation, that yields: `ImportError: No module named setuptools`. So as you can see I'm pretty much paralyzed. :/ Thanks for taking the time to comment though!

Comment: Did you try reinstalling the package with `yum`? `yum reinstall python-setuptools`

Comment: Also, you don't have `setuptools` but `pip` still imports that from somewhere - can you post the complete error trace?

Comment: @hoefling I tried your reinstall command and it appeared successful. But then when I tried using pip it still failed with the same message. I will add the error trace in my original post.

Comment: Can you post the output of `yum list installed | grep setuptools` and `grep ^Version: /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-*.egg-info/PKG-INFO`?

Comment: @hoefling I did this; check my edit. From the second one it looks like I might be missing something important...

Comment: Ok, so `setuptools` should be installed now - can you confirm you have the `pkg_resources.py` module? Run `ls /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py; echo $?`, if this command outputs 0, remove the `pkg_resources` package: `sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/`. **Remove the dir only when the pkg_resources module is found!** After that, `pip` should work again: run smth like `pip list` to check that.

Comment: @hoefling IT WORKED!!! Now of course I'm running into a plethora of other problems with actually getting the proper modules INSTALLED, but it's nice to at least be able to use pip!! Thank you so much for your help! I had resigned myself to life without pip before this...

Comment: Nice, glad I could help!

Answer (score 10):

I've got the same error with python2.6 on redHat server 6.9 :

```
pip version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 947, in <module>
    class Environment(object):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 951, in Environment
    self, search_path=None, platform=get_supported_platform(),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 180, in get_supported_platform
    plat = get_build_platform()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 380, in get_build_platform
    from sysconfig import get_platform
ImportError: No module named sysconfig
```

I removed :

```
rm /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources*
```

and i reinstalled python-setuptools

```
yum reinstall python-setuptools
```

After this fix :

```
pip --version
pip 7.1.0 from /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (python 2.6)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with

`python3 -m ensurepip --default-pip`

then do

`pip3 install [package]`

this will instruct python to use pip3

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem on Cent6.9 and the instructions here didn't quite fix the problem. The fix the same issue, I needed to backup my entire /usr/lib/python2.6/ folder, and copy them to a new folder with only the modules yum, urlgrabber, and rpmUtils (otherwise yum will break).

**Keep in mind that this fix can seriously break your system (either by breaking yum, or by removing in-use python modules). This will uninstall every single python module. This will also uninstall python34!**

```
cd /usr/lib/
cp -a python2.6 python2.6-bak
cd /usr/lib/python2.6
rm -rf ./* #ow
cp -a /usr/lib/python2.6-bak/site-packages/yum /usr/lib/python2.6/
cp -a /usr/lib/python2.6-bak/site-packages/urlgrabber /usr/lib/python2.6/
cp -a /usr/lib/python2.6-bak/site-packages/rpmUtils /usr/lib/python2.6/
rpm -qa | grep python34 | xargs yum -y erase
rpm -qa | grep python | xargs yum -y reinstall
yum -y reinstall python-setuptools python2-setuptools python-pip
```

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/733):

> When I ran into this, it was caused by having /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/ conflicting with /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py. Erasing the directory allowed everything to work as before. I assume a pip install was the cause, but don't know which package.

Helped me too - `rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources` (**use at your own risk !**).

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

Remove completely `python-setuptools` and delete the folder from `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/`.

then remove manually from the `site-packages` folder the module: `pyOpenSSL` it was after trying to upgrade it that everything went south.

`rm -rf pyOpenSSL-18.0.0-py2.6.egg/`

install back from sudo `python-setuptools` now `pip list` can list the modules and no more errors with `easy_install` either.