# ImportError: No module named 'requests.packages.urllib3'

Tags: python, urllib3

I am testing an application and I am getting the above error "ImportError: No module named 'requests.packages.urllib3'" Below are the details.

```
[root@lab ~]# python /opt/test/panda_API.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/test/panda_API.py", line 8, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .exceptions import InvalidURL
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/exceptions.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.exceptions import HTTPError as BaseHTTPError
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 99, in load_module
    raise ImportError("No module named '%s'" % (name,))
ImportError: No module named 'requests.packages.urllib3'
```

In a bid to resolve that, I try to `pip install requests`. Then the following error pops up.

```
[root@lab ~]# pip install requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 954, in <module>
    class Environment:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 958, in Environment
    self, search_path=None, platform=get_supported_platform(),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 188, in get_supported_platform
    plat = get_build_platform()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 388, in get_build_platform
    from sysconfig import get_platform
ImportError: No module named sysconfig
```

I have searched for solution here on stack overflow and other platforms, the closest is the one in this page on stack overflow. ([ImportError: No module named sysconfig--can't get pip working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50742538/importerror-no-module-named-sysconfig-cant-get-pip-working/52207390?noredirect=1#comment91364742_52207390)).

I have tried the steps proposed in the above link, yet the same error "ImportError: No module named sysconfig", keeps repeating.

Running "pip -V", generated the same error.
Running the recommended command to check the version of setuptools, generated the following error --------

```
    [root@lab pkg_resources]# python2.6 -c "import setuptools; print(setuptools.__version__)"
`Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 14, in <module     >
      import setuptools.version
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
      import pkg_resources
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 954, in <mo     dule>
      class Environment:
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 958, in Env     ironment
      self, search_path=None, platform=get_supported_platform(),
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 188, in get     _supported_platform
      plat = get_build_platform()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 388, in get     _build_platform
      from sysconfig import get_platform
  ImportError: No module named sysconfig
```

I have checked /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages, and I do not have `pkg_resources.py`. Instead, what I have is the directory `pkg_resources`.

It appears that I have a more complicated case. Please I need help please!

Notes:

OS: `CentOS release 6.10 (Final)`, and Python Version: `Python 2.6.6`

Comment: Python 2.6 is still supported?

Comment: Nope. Even 2.7 will be dead soon enough.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is legacy and outdated, referring to a language version which is essentially dead.

Answer (score 2):

firstly run this command,

```
pip install requests urllib3 pyOpenSSL --force --upgrade
```

then install pyOpenSSL version 16.2.0 and run this command

```
pip install pyOpenSSL==16.2.0
```

Answer (score -1):

Update your distribution packages! `Python 2.6` is dead.